# Bootstrap. Как показать вкладку tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap компонент Tab. Создал несколько вкладок... При загрузке страницы я устанавливаю одну из вкладок hidden.

По событию делаю этой вкладке show()... почему то не помогает...

Как показать вкладку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не могу сказать по вашему коду, так как вы его не представили, но данный пример, отработал у меня без ошибок.

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  }
});

$('#button').click(function() {
  var tab = $('#tab');
  if (tab.is(':visible')) {
    tab.hide();
  } else {
    tab.show();
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="http://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-docs-example">
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#profile" id="tab" style="display:none" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
      <p>Скрытая вкладка</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown1">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown2">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Show/Hide</button>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erv8fedh/289/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljzxhx47/ я так делал... вместо style="display:none" почему-то добавил class="hidden"    :))

Comment: Используйте  style="display:none"

Answer (score 0):

А как вы ставите hidden?? Вроде как show/hide переключает лишь свойство display и если у вас указано opacity то ничего не произойдет и элемент не появится